# Shorten form input length via CSS

Tags: css, mailchimp

I'm trying to shorten the length of certain form input fields from an embedded mailchimp signup code. I've tried adding a size tag in each input field but that doesn't work. I think I need to edit with CSS. I don't know how to reference each individual input field and shrink the length. Can anyone help please? I haven't had a chance to start learning CSS yet.

Thanks a million!

```
 <style type="text/css">
    #mc_embed_signup{background:#fff; clear:left; font:14px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; }
    /* Add your own MailChimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this style block.
       We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your HTML file. */

#form input[type="email"] {

    width: 100px;
}

</style>
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="//GNND.us9.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=9c4e5486333883976fbe87bb0&amp;id=f4b7e7abf4" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
    <h2>Subscribe to our mailing list</h2>
<div class="indicates-required"><span class="asterisk">*</span> indicates required</div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
    <label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
</label>
    <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
</div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
    <label for="mce-FNAME">First Name  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no element with `id="form"`, so the selector won't match anything.

You can match the form element instead:

```
form input[type="email"]
```

Or use the actual id of the form:

```
#mc-embedded-subscribe-form input[type="email"]
```

Comment: Guffa, I've tried both examples here. And can't get either to change the input length.

I used 

`#mc-embedded-subscribe-form input[type="email"]{

width: 50px;
}
`


Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @RyanDenham: Inspect the element in the browser, so that you see which CSS actually applies to the element. There might be a more specific rule that overrides that one, or there might even be a style set on the element which you can't override using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little "brute force" but that worked for me with `!important`, like the following:

```
#mc-embedded-subscribe-form input[type="email"]{ width: 300px!important; }
```